# Is there an extension/command line for OSX Chromium to save website passwords in LOCALSTORAGE instead of the system's keychain?

Tags: password-management, macos, chrome

My situation: I want to use a portable-app implementation of Chromium running on a removable drive, so I never leave any passwords stored on the kaychain of any computer I use.

Portable Chromium is great: The app's Local storage, Application Support and Preference folders are directed internally (stored inside the app package on my removable drive). This applies to Extensions like Mailvelope and Darkwallet, etc.

However, "Do you want Chrome to store this password?" passwords are still stored on the OSX keychain, which I want to avoid.

Is there a password-keychain chrome extension that can store my gmail, etc password in Chromium's local storage on my removable drive?

Or is this just such a bad idea...?